# How to downsampling time series data in pandas?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have a time series in pandas that looks like this (order by id):

```
id    time    value
 1       0        2
 1       1        4
 1       2        5
 1       3       10
 1       4       15
 1       5       16
 1       6       18
 1       7       20
 2      15        3
 2      16        5
 2      17        8
 2      18       10
 4       6        5
 4       7        6
```

I want downsampling time from 1 minute to 3 minutes for each group id.
And value is a maximum of group (id and 3 minutes).

The output should be like:

```
id    time    value
 1       0        5
 1       1       16
 1       2       20
 2       0        8
 2       1       10
 4       0        6
```

I tried loop it take long time process.

Any idea how to solve this for large dataframe?

Thanks!

Comment: are you looking for every third occurence in time column? also please paste the code you tried so far.  `df.iloc[::3, :]` which takes a row/column slice, both based on integer position

Comment: Yes! I looking for every third occurence and less then three and change group id.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use `np.r_` and `.iloc` with `groupby`:

```
df.groupby('id')['value'].apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[2:len(x):3,-1]])
```

Output:

```
id    
1   2      5
    5     16
    7     20
2   10     8
    11    10
4   13     6
Name: value, dtype: int64
```

Going a little further with column naming etc..

```
df_out = df.groupby('id')['value']\
           .apply(lambda x: x.iloc[np.r_[2:len(x):3,-1]]).reset_index()
df_out.assign(time=df_out.groupby('id').cumcount()).drop('level_1', axis=1)
```

Output:

```
   id  value  time
0   1      5     0
1   1     16     1
2   1     20     2
3   2      8     0
4   2     10     1
5   4      6     0
```

Comment: Nice could add a [:3] to x.iloc to limit the amount to max 3? Or I could have missunderstood OPs text too..

Comment: @AntonvBR I don't understand what your suggesting.  Can you elobarate more?

Comment: Sorry for slow reply, went for a breakfast. I read between the lines that OP wants to limit the amount of values per group to 3. And in that case add a [:3] selector or a max(9, len(x)) statement somehow.

Answer (score 7):

You can convert your `time` series to an actual `timedelta`, then use `resample` for a vectorized solution:

```
t = pd.to_timedelta(df.time, unit='T')
s = df.set_index(t).groupby('id').resample('3T').last().reset_index(drop=True)
s.assign(time=s.groupby('id').cumcount())
```

```
   id  time  value
0   1     0      5
1   1     1     16
2   1     2     20
3   2     0      8
4   2     1     10
5   4     0      6
```

Comment: I like this way better.  I actually thought about doing this first, but for some reason I didnt think it would work.  +1